# How to import data from one table to another in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

There're two tables in database

table `users` with some datas

```
username invitedby
123      23
12       45
89433    11893
faf      123
afsafgf  12
```

table `list`

```
lname  type
```

I want to import data from `users` to `list`, and the `list` data show like this

```
lname  type
123      3
12       3
89433    3
faf      3
afsafgf  3
123      2
12       2
```

First, import all datas into `users`, and `lname` is from `username`, and set the `type` to be 3.

Second, if some `username` inivited another, such as `faf` is invited by `123`, `afsafgf` is invited by `12`, insert the inviter and set its type to be 2, the last two line data above.

How can I write this SQL query in mysql? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into list (lname, type)
    select username, 3
    from users
    union all
    select invitedby, 2
    from users u
    where exists (select 1 from users u2 where u2.username = u.invitedby);
```